# Is there a way to update a jgrowl message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, growl

Is there a way using jgrowl(or any other growl like popup) to update a message if it hasn't been removed yet and if it has been removed just simply add it like normal?

Comment: Lol @ jgrowl.  Sounds like a rapper.

Comment: Updating an existing message is a big illogical as the whole purpose of the popup is to catch the user's attention without forcing him to act. 

The more logical way, IMO, would be to close the message and create a new one.

Comment: @Ariel, Good idea. I think that maybe work better.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found some changes that will make it possible to do what I want with jgrowl. http://www.moonlitscript.com/post.cfm/jgrowl-modification

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the plugin, I think an easier way would be to make a function to find text inside the growl, then remove it. I've tested the code below, it works and it doesn't appear to cause any problems with the plugin.

This function will remove the growl based on it's contents

```
function clearGrowl(txt){
 $('.jGrowl-notification:contains("' + txt + '")').remove();
}
```

If you only want to target the header of the growl, then modify it as follows:

```
function clearGrowl(txt){
 $('.jGrowl-notification .header:contains("' + txt + '")').remove();
}
```